# .Net AsyncFileupload how to change 'PostBackurl'

Tags: asp.net, ajax

i am stuck in a small problem. You see my page uses friendly url like http://mydomain.com/page/subpage/ but then it internally gets mapped to http://mydomain.com/edit/name.aspx.

AsyncFileupload puts out this script tag in the html as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.Application.initialize();
Sys.Application.add_init(function () {
    $create(AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload, { "clientStateField":   $get("ctl00_FullRegion_MainRegion_ContentRegion_ContentFullRegion_EditProfile_fileUpload1_ClientState"), "completeBackColor": "White", "errorBackColor": "Red", "formName": "aspnetForm", "hiddenField": $get("ctl00_FullRegion_MainRegion_ContentRegion_ContentFullRegion_EditProfile_fileUpload1_ctl00"), "inputFile": $get("ctl00_FullRegion_MainRegion_ContentRegion_ContentFullRegion_EditProfile_fileUpload1_ctl02"), "postBackUrl": "name.aspx", "uploadingBackColor": "#CCFFFF" }, { "uploadComplete": uploadComplete, "uploadError": uploadError }, null, $get("ctl00_FullRegion_MainRegion_ContentRegion_ContentFullRegion_EditProfile_fileUpload1"));
});
//]]>
</script>
```

now when user tries to upload a file the url converts to http://mydomain.com/page/subpage/name.aspx which obviously doesn't work is there any way i could change the "PostBackUrl" to "http://mydomain.com/edit/name.aspx"??

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work?  If you navigate directly to `http://mydomain.com/edit/name.aspx` is that where you end up?

Comment: @mason actually when user uploads a file an alert is shown as " http://mydomain.com/page/subpage/name.aspx" (404) Resouce not found

Comment: and yes both the url's work fine http://mydomain.com/page/subpage/ & http://mydomain.com/edit/name.aspx.

Comment: anyone??? not sure what has to be done here :/